# UIpath excel file read/write

Tags: excel, uipath

I want to implement an automatic process for excel data using UIpath. I am following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ed3hYpKofts&t=266s.
However, on minute 4:23, it can set the variable into read/write excel.

I am following the exact step with the video. however, my variable has no option for read/write excel. Has anyone ever experience this? please let me know what I miss.

[image: no read/write]

Comment: That's just the scope of the variable. His activity is named "Read/Write Excel..." so that variable is within the scope of that activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope is where the variable exists. It must be a container. In your case, yo have 2 containers, `Sequence` and `Do`. If you set the scope of a variable to the scope `Do`, it only will exist in that scope. If you set it for Sequence, it will exist, in this case, in all the `main`.

With that said, if it doesn't appear to you the `read/write` scope, it's because you didn't change the `sequence` name. You can change it in properties, it's called `displayName`. After that, it will appear in the scope with that name.